# Windows Azure SDK for Android - how to exclude a property of DTO from serialization?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to use Azure Mobile service for persisting data from my Android app.
The issue I am having now is that I have a data transfer object with several fields corresponding to columns in Azure database table. And I have one field, which I DON"T want to persist. I am trying to use @Expose annotation, but it doesn't seem to work, I am getting an exception from Azure saying that SubCategories has invalid data type. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.mycorp.myapp.model;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.annotations.*;

public class Category {

    public Category(){
        SubCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    }

    public int Id;

    public String Name;

    public int ParentId;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    List<Category> SubCategories;
}
```

And code below returns a MobileServiceException ({"code":400,"error":"Error: The value of property 'SubCategories' is of type 'object' which is not a supported type."})

```
Category category = new Category();     
category.Name = "new";
category.ParentId = 1;      
mClient.getTable(Category.class).insert(category, new TableOperationCallback<Category>() {          
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Category entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if(exception!=null)
            {
                Log.e("Service error", exception.getMessage());
            }               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, @Expose annotation is ignored if you use default Gson constructor as described [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html).

I was able to solve my problem by removing Expose and making the field transient:

```
package com.mycorp.myapp.model;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.annotations.*;

public class Category {

    public Category(){
        SubCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    }

    public int Id;

    public String Name;

    public int ParentId;

    //@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    transient List<Category> SubCategories;
}
```